# Who can read config values set by functions:config:set command?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm working on the implementation of some Cloud Functions for Firebase and one of these require some configuration to call external providers.

I was able to successfully configure these values using `firebase functions:config:set key="value"` but I was wondering what are the actors able to read this value.

Is the function the only capable of read it? Should I encrypt `"value"`? At the end will have to have the key in order to decrypt it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment configuration is created exactly for keeping some settings or 3rd-party services keys.

Only your google functions will be able to extract the value on remote environment.
Also you can check those values locally using `firebase functions:config:get key` command.

To get those variables from the code of your function use this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const someEnvVar = functions.config().key  
// where key is name of key you setted before
```

See more in [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)